# Jquery motion blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-plugins

I am working for a company and converting flash ad banners in html5.

I need to convert flash image which slides in from the left and at the same time it performs motion blur effect just like a windy effect.

I have converted slide in image but I am not sure how to add a windy effect.

Here is the  [car image](http://platform.mediamind.com/Eyeblaster.Preview.Web/AdPreview.aspx?reportinteractions=0&adid=20986603) I want to copy and this is my code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veDY6/)
Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<div id = "wrapper" >       
 <div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="text">
        <img id="Image_Car" src="http://i.share.pho.to/c43dc6d7_o.png" />
    </div>  
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    height:250px;
    position: absolute;
}
#mainContainer {
    background: url('https://secure-ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingRes/Site-8188/Type-0/5fefb401-b187-4d82-b4db-cbd2ef29cc48.gif');
    width:300px;
    height:250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
#Image_Car {
    position:absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:60px 8px;
    left: -120px;
}
```

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     bannerAnimation();
 });

 function bannerAnimation() {
     //Jquery Animation
     $("#Image_Car").animate({
         left: "30"
     }, 500, function () {
         $("#Image_Car").animate({
             left: "10"
         }, 200);
     });
 }
```

Comment: a comment is you can separate your question into paragraph and use topic sentences, it would help a lot

Comment: Your car image seems to be a white, grey-bordered rectangle (iPad Air/iOS 7).

Comment: David i have different car images and this image i have used for the testing. this is not a actual image. I am just trying to copy the windy image.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is very good plugin for you:
[DEMO](http://tympanus.net/Development/Windy/)

[plugin](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/09/windy-a-plugin-for-swift-content-navigation/)

Comment: @user3718016 pleas check this answer as your answer. click on the  tick. and Yes you should see the documentation on http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/09/windy-a-plugin-for-swift-content-navigation/

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is not going to help you create motion blur unless you use a canvas, which nearly no one use for creating ads,

**or**,

you can create multiple instance of the images and place in same place, then animate each with slight time interval and opacity.

Comment: Have you seen the demo? . My problem is that image can be replaced with any car image and i need to produce the same effect or at least something closer than that effect